# POSIX-compatible regex library for Visual Studio C

Tags: c, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, posix

I'm working on a C program which will be run in Linux and from inside Visual Studio 2010, and I'm looking for a regex library.  GNU comes with a POSIX-compatible regex library, but Visual Studio, despite having C++ std::regex, doesn't have a C-compatible library.  GNU has a Windows version of their library (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/regex.htm), but the DLLs are 32-bit only and the source code can't compile in Visual Studio (~500 errors!).  My only requirement is that the end-user should not have to install anything extra, and should get the same behaviour on both platforms.  I'm not picky about whether it's POSIX-style, Perl-style or something else.  What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at PCRE: http://www.pcre.org

Comment: [`boost` provides a POSIX-compatible set of C APIs.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/regex/doc/posix_api.html)

Comment: PCRE doesn't compile in VS either; boost seems to be all C++ code, despite their claims to POSIX compatibility, and I'm not sure how much I'd have to change to get it to work with a C compiler.

Comment: PCRE compiles just fine for me under MSVC 6.0 (PCRE source is 100% pure ANSI C) so should compile just fine with any version. (You do need to fiddle with a few Win32-specific `DEFINE`s, in a couple header files but rest assured, it _does_ compile.)

Comment: Have you considered creating a small C wrapper around `std::regex`, perhaps in a separate library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one library I've found that compiles with basically no effort, and is also the smallest, is: https://code.google.com/p/slre/.  It's pretty basic but is good enough for my purposes.  Thanks for the help, though.