# How to use regex in C/Where to find the files?

Tags: c, regex

I want to use regex and I saw that the POSIX regular expression library provides functions but how do I include the library? Where to find the files? I googled a lot and did not find any manual.
Can anyone help me by providing a manual or a link to a manual? I am using Visual Studio Code

Comment: If you're on a POSIX system (like Linux or macOS) then you should already have it. Read any tutorial on how to link with libraries, and especially tutorials on how to use and build with the regex library.

Comment: Try: `man 3 regex`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no I have windows. So it is not included? Can I include it somehow

Comment: @tshiono Thank you I will try it!. Edit: I did not find any manual or files I could include.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296404/posix-compatible-regex-library-for-visual-studio-c

Comment: If you are on windows, you will need a library.  Here is one page: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/regex.htm

Comment: Also really useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631450/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-c

Comment: Another regex library - if you want to use Boost: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Hey thank you for all the useful links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C by itself doesn't have regex, but there are multiple libraries providing this functionality, like:

- PCRE and PCRE2 - http://www.pcre.org/
- libgnurx - https://github.com/TimothyGu/libgnurx
- TRE - http://laurikari.net/tre/about/
- sregex - https://github.com/openresty/sregex
- slre - https://github.com/cesanta/slre
- liblightgrep - https://github.com/strozfriedberg/liblightgrep
- RxSpencer - https://github.com/garyhouston/rxspencer
- RE2 - https://github.com/google/re2/
- Oniguruma - https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma
- Onigmo - https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo
- Hyperscan - https://www.hyperscan.io/

And there are probably more regex libraries out there.

I have been able to compile all of the above from source for Windows using MinGW-w64.

Most commonly used are PCRE, PCRE2, libgnurx, but Oniguruma and Hyperscan are interesting alternatives.

If you're using C++ there is also std::regex or boost::regex.